# Regularity of test functions in the definition of the total variation distance

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

As is well-known, the total variation distance between (the laws of) two random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ is given by
$\sup |E[g(X)]-E[g(Y)]|$, where the supremum is taken over all measurable $g:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ that are measurable. Here is my question: do we obtain the same definition if one considers the supremum over all $g:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ that are continuous? Or over all $g:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ that are $C^1$?

Thanks

Comment: The total variation between the laws of $X$ and $Y$ is the Kantorovich-Wasserstein-Monge-Rubinshtein-... distance induced by the discrete metric on $\mathbb{R}$ - see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) for the properties of this distance, but I would be careful about the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is not separable under the discrete metric.